# Java Stripes handlesEvent fire before ValidationMethod?

Tags: java, stripes

due to a variety of constraints, I need a method with HandlesEvent annotation to fire before another method with ValidationMethod annotation.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifiy that the validationMethod is only for certain events you can control it.

E.g.

```
  @ValidationMethod(on={"useradminsubmit"}) 
  public void checkWhatever(ValidationErrors errors) {
      ....
  }
```

If your `handleEvent` method is not included then the validation will not fire.

Comment: Basically I'm putting some toggled code in, because we are changing architecture. I need to either: (a) Add my new event  to the @Validation method, and set a variable inside the Bean, before the ValidationMethod fires. Or (b) Don't add my event to the Validation method, set my variable, then explicitly call the ValidationMethods, (and some how figure out how to pass in ValidationErrors error parameter...

Comment: How about just extending your class?